# For loop(s) not working as intended with graphics

Tags: java, for-loop, graphics

I've been trying to make a for loop that horizontally replicates vertical lines across the screen, each the same distance apart from its precedent; however, my code doesn't seem to work despite appearing to be syntactically correct. I've posted my code below, hopefully someone can identify the problem.

```
class HVLines
{
    public static void Lines(Graphics g)
     {
    int k;
    int x=0;

        for (k = 1; k <= 50; k++)
         {
      g.drawLine(20+x,150,20+x,525);

        for (x = 1; x <= 50; x+=20)
            {

            }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: What purpose does the empty inner loop serve? Yes your syntax is "correct" meaning it compiles, but it makes no logical sense. Don't code without working out the logic first, off the computer and separately on paper.

Comment: There's no code in the inner loop on `x`, so it's doing nothing (except wasting CPU time). The `drawLine()` call in the outer loop will draw with `x = 0` on the first iteration, and with `x = 61` on all subsequent iterations. Perhaps move it inside inner loop? And what is purpose of `k` loop? If you had declared the variables in the loops, you'd have noticed the misused of `x`, e.g. `for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x+=20)`

Comment: Please improve the question: show an image of what you're trying to achieve, explain what you think each line of code is doing... A little more detail can help us understand what you're trying to achieve and why you're not achieving it.

Comment: Here's an image of what I am essentially trying to achieve:
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/U1zHS9f.png">

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should look like this. I can't ensure it will work since I don't know how you use it. Also, in your loops, you use `x` twice, but don't use `k`. Change one of those, or , if you don't need it, erase one of the loops.

I am prett sure this one creates a diagonal line, not horizontal.

```
for (k = 1; k <= 50; k++)  {
    for (x = 1; x <= 50; x+=20) {
        // Choose one of the following
        g.drawLine(20+k,150,20+x,525);
        g.drawLine(20+x,150,20+k,525);
    }
}
```

This one creates a straight line:

```
for (x = 1; x <= 50; x+=20) {
    g.drawLine(20+x,150,20+x,525);
}
```

Comment: What purpose does the outer loop serve. How can you answer such an incomplete incomprehensible question, knowing what the code should "look like"?

Comment: It is obvious he wanted to use `k` and `x`. He forgot to use one of those, don't be picky.

Comment: I'd prefer to wait for him to clarify his question so that it can be answered in an intelligent way. Posting nonsense code like the above isn't helping him or future visitors.

Comment: Both possibilities added. Happpy ?

Comment: The outer loop's intention was to repeat the function contained inside and to repeat the lines. After taking into consideration the removal of the outer loop, it was in-fact unnecessary to begin with. The outer loop wasn't performing the function I believed it to be doing. Post-removal, my program runs as intended.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class DrawLine extends JApplet {
    public void init() {
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.white);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setPaint(Color.gray);
        for (int y = 0; y <= 300; y += 30) {
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, y, 300, y));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Line");
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JApplet applet = new DrawLine();
        f.getContentPane().add("Center", applet);
        applet.init();
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```